# Windows installation and laptop recovery

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation

All,

I want to install windows 7 on my laptop. It has genuine windows vista and its recovery is on the partition. Now I want to know if there is any way that I install Windows 7 on my laptop and then will there be any way to restore original windows vista again from recovery.

Comment: As long as the boot options and recovery partition are left intact then yes, you should be able to recover Vista again in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you delete the recovery partition, you will be able to restore the factory install of Windows Vista at a later date by using the recovery method provided by the manufacturer. Make sure you understand that procedure and do not remove any boot options or partitions provided by the OEM.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want to know if there is any way that I install Windows 7 on my
>   laptop and then will there be any way to restore original windows
>   vista again from recovery.

In both the case of an in-place upgrade and a fresh installation the current installation of Windows is lost.  While the installer will move your current windows installation to `Windows.old` migrating back to this data is easier said then done.

If you are thinking about upgrading be sure you backup your data.

If you have a factory recovery partition you can also uses that.  I am not entirely sure the reason you would want to use that.